# Java cast oracleconnection eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, casting, database-connection

please tell me if I have to provide more information/code, becasue I am a newbie in java and maybe don't know which informations you need.

I have to add a functionality to an existing Eclipse RCP application. In this I need to register an `OracleDatabaseChangeListenet` to my database connection.

The problem is, the connection already exists and is of the self-designed class `Connection` (is designed the way, that connections to other databases except Oracle are possible)  that implements self-designed interface `IConnection`, but basically this connection is to an Oracle 11g database.

So I need to cast this connection to `OracleConnection`, but get an `CastExceptionError`. How can I manage to cast the connection?

```
    public void openConnection( IConnection connection) throws JeffException {
    URI conURI = connection.getUri();

    String con_System = conURI.getPath().split( "/")[1]; //$NON-NLS-1$
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + conURI.getHost() + ":" + conURI.getPort() + "/" + con_System; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
    String Jeff_user = connection.getProperty( DatabaseConstants.JEFF_USERNAME);
    String Jeff_password = connection.getProperty( DatabaseConstants.JEFF_PASSWORD);
    //derby-embedded
    //        jdbcUrl="jdbc:derby:embeddedDB1;create=true";
    String Jeff_proxy_password = connection.getProperty( DatabaseConstants.JEFF_PROXY_PASSWORD);
    String Jeff_proxy_username = connection.getProperty( DatabaseConstants.JEFF_PROXY_USERNAME);
    OracleConnection conn=(OracleConnection) connection;
```

The error I get is

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: mapackage.projectmanager.model.Connection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: This design makes no sense to me.  What improvement does your self-designed IConnection offer over the java.sql.Connection?  That's the only interface that JDBC drivers have to know about.

Comment: It is not my design, as mentioned above I have to extend an existing application and it was designed so at the start. It would be too much extrawork for me if I had to redesign this especially as a newbie, so if possible I would like to let it this way and simply cast the connection to OracleConenction. Should I post the code of Connection class?